# How to plot 2D numpy coordinate array with corresponding RGB array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have a 2D numpy array of coordinates (x, y) with dimensions 40000x2 that I am running through a machine learning model. I converted the prediction to an RGB numpy array with dimensions 40000x3. Each entry (row) from the RGB array corresponds to the same entry of the coordinates array.

I want to be able to quickly plot everything. Before, I tried using the scatter() function, but it took too long.

```
# Fragment of code I used before
# coordArray (40000x2), rgbArray (40000x3)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
for i in range(len(coordArray)):
    ax.scatter(coordArray[i, 0], coordArray[i, 1], marker='o', 
    c=rgbArray[i], s=1.5, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

I was wondering if there was a better/quicker way to plot the data. For reference, I am also plotting my training set and test set (just not shown in the code fragment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a suitable `np.array` and fill the coordinates with the values from `rgbArray`. Then plot the array with [`plt.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). Missing coordinates will be plotted as black.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Example with 3 coordinates in a 2x2 array
# [0,0] -> red
# [0,1] -> green
# [1,1] -> blue
# [1,0] -> 'no information'
coord = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
rgb = np.array([[1.,0.,0.],[0.,1.,0.],[0.,0.,1.]])

img = np.zeros(tuple(coord.max(0)+1)+(3,))

img[coord[:,0],coord[:,1]] = rgb
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off');
```

Out:

[image: image from coordinates]

---

If you want a scatter plot there is no need to iterate over your arrays. You can use:

```py
plt.scatter(coord[:,0],coord[:,1], color=rgb, s=20);
```

Out:

[image: scatter plot of same data]

Comment: Is there any way to use floats? My coordinate array mostly comprises of floating point numbers.

Comment: You can just use `floats` in the `rgb` array. It's even a little bit simpler. I updated my answer to use `floats` in the example data.

Comment: For the coordinate data I would need an example. The `scatter` solution without iterating could be more suitable in this case. For the 'imshow' approach we could [`MinMaxTransform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) and convert to `int`.

Comment: If the coordinates values are not integer numbers this approach won't work

Answer (score 1):

Using vectorized code is likely to speed-up the plotting:

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.scatter(coordArray[:, 0], coordArray[:, 1], 
           marker='o', c=rgbArray/255, s=1.5, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

Note that the entries of `rgbArray` must be in the range [0,1].